# Shocked at sites that copy/paste the Stack Overlow look and feel without changing anything

Tags: discussion, user-interface, uservoice

Most egregious this is. I was shocked, and dare I say, rather apoplectic, as I came upon a site in blantant copy use of the colors and UI elements which are seen on Stack Overflow.

To the room, I present: http://feedback.odesk.com/forums/26681-general

Are there a lot of other sites that copy/paste Stack Overflow's feel without changing almost anything?

Comment: should go to meta.stackoverflow.com

Comment: I suppose on internet there always copy cats

Comment: The man, is shocked, dare I say, *apoplectic*!!!!!!!11!!!oneoneone

Answer (score 11):

That's UserVoice. It [kinda existed *before* SO](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/stack-overflow-private-beta-begins/#comment-4864)...

Comment: ? Don't find oDesk if I search for you link ?
Maybe oDesk existed before SO, but the whole interface has been changed & the JavaScript code too in a very questionnable copy/paste way.

Comment: @Olivier: see the "powered by uservoice" logo in the top right corner of oDesk. Also see: http://uservoice.com/

Comment: SO didn't invent questions, comments, voting, nor badges either. It just combined them in a very clever way. Whether copying that way 1:1 can be a success? I don't know. We'll see.

Comment: Own that quesion by associating your accounts: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2508/account-association-between-websites @oli

Comment: @Greg: you're perfeclty right. >_< .Sometimes I should "Carve every word before you let it fall" (French translation of "Il faut tourner sept fois sa langue dans sa bouche avant de parler"). >_< . My mistake.

Comment: @Olivier: N'ayez pas de soucis. :)